Reactive Extensions operators for pattern matching
I'd like to subscribe to a stream and get a notification if a certain sequence of events are observed.
Something like - in very much pseudo code: .WhenType<MessageHandled>().ThenType<TransactionCommitted>().ThenAnyNumberOfAnyType().ThenType<QueueStopped>().
Like a regex, but filtering on events/types in the stream rather than a string.
What's the best way to accomplish something like that?

I tried using Observable Joins (see Guide to System.Reactive.Joins), but couldn't get a working solution.
I did, however, try a state machine option and got something that works.
I started by creating an enum that represents your states. I know you're using types, but the enum makes my example clearer.
public enum Value
{
    MessageHandled,
    TransactionCommitted,
    QueueStopped,
    X,
    Y,
}

I then created an observable that returns various combinations of these values.
IObservable<Value> source = new[]
{
    /* invalid */ Value.TransactionCommitted, Value.TransactionCommitted, Value.MessageHandled, Value.X,
    /* valid */ Value.MessageHandled, Value.TransactionCommitted, Value.X, Value.Y, Value.QueueStopped,
    /* invalid */ Value.X, Value.X,
    /* valid */ Value.MessageHandled, Value.TransactionCommitted, Value.QueueStopped,
    /* invalid */ Value.Y, Value.MessageHandled, Value.Y, Value.TransactionCommitted, Value.QueueStopped,
}.ToObservable();

I created an enum for the states, and a definition for the initial states of the state machine and the transitions.
public enum State { A, B, Z }

var initial = new (Value value, State state)[]
{
    (Value.MessageHandled, State.A),
};

var transitions = new(State current, Func<Value, bool> rule, State next)[]
{
    (State.A, t => t == Value.TransactionCommitted, State.B),
    (State.B, t => t != Value.QueueStopped, State.B),
    (State.B, t => t == Value.QueueStopped, State.Z),
};

And finally, here's the query that runs the state machine:
IObservable<Value[]> query =
    source
        .Scan(
            new List<(State state, Value[] values)>(),
            (accumulator, value) =>
            (
                Enumerable
                    .Concat(
                        from a in accumulator
                        from t in transitions
                        where a.state == t.current
                        where t.rule(value)
                        select (t.next, a.values.Append(value).ToArray()),
                        from i in initial
                        where i.value == value
                        select (i.state, new[] { value }))
            ).ToList())
        .SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.state == State.Z), (x, y) => y.values);

That produced:

And, based on your description, that's what I think you wanted.
